# Producing a boost converter, difference with theoretical analysis

Tags: power, boost, converter

[image]

I'm trying to reproduce a boost converter with these specifications:

- Po=200W
- Vin=40V
- Vout=120V
- L=100uH
- switching frequency 100kHz

I tried it but the load power does not reach 200W and Iout isn't 1.66A, either. I set the load to be 72 so that 1.66*72=200.

What can I do to get this done correctly?

[image]

Comment: Please show us your equations.

Comment: I put the equations. pretty sure this is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1N5819 is a schottky diode rated for 40V reverse voltage, so the circuit will not work: the diode will breakdown and conduct in reverse. You need a diode with higher reverse voltage rating, 150V at least.

I think LTSpice models this. You can verify by plotting diode current. If it goes in the wrong direction, then the model is correct.

Also you're using a 100V MOSFET with 120V across it. When the FET switches off, there will be a voltage spike on the drain so it will reach higher voltage than Vout, so you must use at least a 150V FET if the layout is tight, but a 200V FET would be much safer.

Answer (score 2):

You need everything to match. The 72 Ohm resistor load guarantees that Pout will be 200 when Vout is 120.

The problem is that Vout is less than 120V. So increase the duty cycle slightly until it reaches 120V. I guess you calculated the duty cycle neglecting losses, and consequently, you came up with a too low duty cycle to get the desired output.

Please note that a boost converter typically is designed to produce a specific output voltage. It does not (usually) regulate power or current. Also, note that the load puts limits on the relationship between output power, current and voltage. The power source (your boost regulator) is not free to adjust all three parameters (output voltage, current and power). The load imposes limits on them.

Comment: I tried increasing D but Vout never exceeds 110V...I tried changing MOSFETs but can't get the wanted values

Comment: Well, since it is just a simulation, how about changing V1 to a constant DC source and see what the steady state DC current is through L1/M1 when M1 is on continuously.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer of mkeith, I see two potential problems with the MOSFET. You are operating near the drain-source breakdown voltage of the MOSFET which is 100 V if you look at the datasheet. Look for a MOSFET with a sufficient vds,max. Also the driving voltage of 4 V is rather low. Try increasing it to something more significantly above threshold. Depending on the MOSFET model, this could be 10 V or 15 V for example.

Answer (score 0):

Using [this on-line tool](http://www.stades.co.uk/Boost%20converter/Boost%20calculator.html) I get a duty cycle of 0.6667: -

[image]

200 watts and 120 volts is a load resistance of 72 Ω so, that is what I used. The tool assumes idea components but the real value for duty cycle will be close and, your circuit will run in CCM.

Full formula derivations on that web page.